# Помощь по программированию на Android

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте! Мне 14 лет. Увлекаюсь программированием. Несколько лет программировал на *Delphi*. Я уехав на море на долгий срок, не взял с собой ноутбук. Но программировать хочется и поэтому я скачал программу *AIDE* - Android IDE - Java, *C++* на свой смартфон. Скачал самоучитель по *Android SDK*, немного разобрался,  но все равно осталось много непонятных моментов. Какой самоучитель или туториал можете предложить по этой программе и по программированию для *Android*?

Comment: KoVadim, AIDE - так в Google play называется.  А за сайт спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самоучитель для AIDE? гугл или удалить и забыть. А по андроиду - рекомендую хороший сайт - startandroid.ru - там можно и pdf скачать с уроками:)